# Django object locking

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I'm using Django 1.8 and I have a model

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now, in my view I want to add a new ModelA object, but only if there are fewer than x entries for that value already.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Using the value of 4 here just as an example
    c = ModelA.objects.filter(some_field=4).count()
    # Check if fewer than (x=20) objects with this field already
    if c < 20:
        # Fewer, so create one
        new_model = ModelA(4)
        new_model.save()
    else:
        # Return a message saying "too many"
```

From my understanding, there could be more than one thread running this method and so thread 1 may perform the count and there are fewer than 20 and then the other thread saves a new object, then thread 1 would save its object and there be 20 or more.

Is there some way to have the view be

```
def my_view(request):
    get_a_lock_on_model(ModelA)
    c = ModelA.objects....
    # Rest of the code the same
    release_lock_on_model(ModelA)
```

Or is there some other way I should be thinking about doing this? There are only ever inserts, never updates or deletes.

Thanks!

Comment: Something to ask yourself, is 20 a hard limit or a soft limit? It'll be rare for two threads to both count 19 and then insert another: will the resulting 21 objects be catastrophic, or just an oddity of no great harm to anything?

Comment: It's a hard limit. The view request might add 1 object, or it might add 4 objects. I need to know that there are sufficient "spaces" to be able to take that number of entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you need to lock the entire table and how to do that depends on the RDBMS that you are using. It will involve the use of raw sql. An alternative approach is to do the count after you have saved your record

```
def my_view(request):
    new_model = ModelA(4)
    new_model.save()

    try :
        c = ModelA.objects.filter(some_field=4)[20]
        if c.pk == new_model.pk:
           c.delete()
        # Return a message saying "too many"

    except IndexError:
        pass
```

This approach does not get in each others way, each thread is responsible for deleting the extra item that it added. Instead of deleting you can use atomic and rollback if the count is greater than 20

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a nice, elegant way of handling it. I probably should have mentioned in the original question that the view request may create one or more objects, and so it needs to make sure that there is enough "space" left to insert all of them. I guess I could just expand this idea you've posted so it will just track all the objects it inserts and then check and delete them all. It just feels like there should be some kind of built-in locking mechanism when Django offers so many things out of the box!

Comment: Django doesn't offer this out of the box because this is a rather unusual scenario and implementation needs a lot of work because databases handle it in different ways

Comment: So how did it go?

Comment: It worked, but I decided to change the way I was handling it in the end. Instead I added a new field to a related object that had the count and updated that in a transaction.atomic() select_for_update way as there could be more than one added at a go. I'll bear this in mind for future uses though. Thanks

Comment: you are welcoe. All the best wtih your project

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Django 1.10.x and postgres:

models.py:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

And:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

n = 42
maximum = 3

raw_sql = RawSQL('select (select count(*) from fooapp_modela where some_field=%s) < %s', (n, maximum))
while True:
    o = ModelA.objects.create(some_field=n, active=raw_sql)
    o.refresh_from_db()
    print(o.id, o.active)
    if not o.active:
        # o.delete()
        break
```

**Caveat**:  By default, while one transaction is active, other transactions on other connections could not "see" inserted rows until the transactions are committed.  Try to avoid creating rows in a complex transactions.  I believe that this means that this method is not completely bullet proof :-( More info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html .

A more robust solution might include a db constraint (probably `unique_together`):

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ordinal = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
         unique_together = (
             ('some_field', 'ordinal'),
         )

#...

raw_sql = RawSQL('select count(*) + 1 from fooapp_modela where some_field=%s', (n,))

o = ModelA.objects.create(some_field=n, ordinal=raw_sql) # retry a few times on IntegrityError
o.refresh_from_db()
print(o.id, o.ordinal)
```